# How to use formula field in Javascript button

Tags: javascript, formula, custom-button

Can we use formula field in javascript button? im getting an error "Incorrect parameter type for function 'or()'. Expected Boolean, received Text".

Account_Inactive__c is formula field on contact object which returns "Active" or "Inactive" if the checkbox on account field is checked and viceversa

```
if( {!or(Account.Inactive_del__c, false)} ) {
    alert('You cannot create a new opp for an Inactive account.');
} 
else if( {!or(Contact.Inactive__c,false)} ) {
    alert('You cannot create a new opp for an Inactive contact.');
}
else if( {!or(Contact.Account_Inactive__c,active)} ) {
    alert('You cannot create a new opp for an Inactive contact.');
}
else
{
    window.top.location.href = "{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New, null, ["retURL"="/"&NULLVALUE(Contact.Id, Account.Id), "00N40000002Gafd"=Account.Location__c, "opp3"=Account.Name&" "&"-","opp4_lkid"=Account.Id,"conid"=Contact.Id], true)}";
}
```

Comment: Hi, Admin_BA. It looks like the code you've written here isn't quite right. This code, as is, should result in a JavaScript compile error, not a merge field error. Could you please doublecheck your code?

Comment: Updated full code, the first 2 conditions work but the third one is throwing error

Comment: Iam geting error "Field active does not exist. Check spelling"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "active" should be "false", just the same as the previous two entries. OR always takes Boolean values, `true` or `false`, or fields that are checkboxes, or comparisons (<, >, !=, =, <>, etc) that compare to `true` or `false`.

Comment: But Account_Inactive__c is formula field (IF(Account.Inactive_del__c,"Inactive", "Active")) that updates value "Active" or "Inactive" how can i use true or false? the formula field is text type

Comment: @Admin_BA That was probably important to mention. In that case, you actually need to use quotes: `{!Contact.Account_Inactive__c="Inactive"}`. Using = will compare two texts and return a Boolean, as you need.